# Configuring Camel-Spring for standalone Camel microservice in a multi-module Gradle project

Tags: spring, gradle, apache-camel, microservices, multi-module

Goal: Adapting [Prototype microservice example from Ch7 of Camel in Action by Claus Ibsen](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter7/prototype) into a Gradle multi-module project.
I followed the Spring Guide to '[Creating a Multi Module Project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/#scratch)' among other resources.

Project Structure:

```
+ main-mm-build
  |--+ src 
        |--+ main
              |--+ java // Spring Boot microservice (A) in this tree
  |--+ build.gradle
  |--+ settings.gradle
  |--+ contact-manager // standalone-camel-spring microservice (B)
        |--+ src 
              |--+ main
                    |--+ java // standalone-camel-spring microservice (B) here
        |--+ build.gradle
```

Got as far as:

1. microservice A (Spring Boot Rest controller) can invoke microservice B (standalone Camel exposing rest() on jetty, without Spring DI).

But what I really want is to use Spring DI (without Spring Boot) in microservice B.
After making changes for camel-spring I get an error.

It's probably mucked up Gradle config, but I could use some help.

```
main-mm-build/contact-manager$ ../gradlew build
main-mm-build/contact-manager$ java -jar build/libs/contact-manager-1.0.jar
.
.
.
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: rest://get:/contact-manager?consumerComponentName=jetty&consumes=application%2Fjson&outType=...dto.ContactDto%5B%5D&produces=application%2Fjson&routeId=route2 due to: null
        at ...impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.getEndpoint(AbstractCamelContext.java:801)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ...camel.spring.spi.ApplicationContextBeanRepository.lookupByNameAndType(Ap..j:45)
```

Root project Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
sourceCompatibility = '11'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

allprojects {
    group = 'el.cam'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    version = '1.0'
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
    rootProject.name = 'main-mm-build'
    include 'contact-manager'
```

Microservice B (contact-manager) build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

sourceCompatibility = '11'

mainClassName = 'el.cam.contacts.ContactManagerApplication'

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes (
                'Main-Class': mainClassName
        )
    }
    baseName = 'contact-manager' + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.3.1.RELEASE"))
    implementation( platform("org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-dependencies:3.0.0-RC3") )

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-rest-starter'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-jetty-starter'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-jackson-starter'
    implementation 'org.apache.camel:camel-swagger-java-starter'//  '3.0.0-RC3'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'


    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

ContactManagerApplication.java ( I wonder if I'm configuring Spring Camel incorrectly here. All the examples I found were based on Spring boot autoconfiguration, so I just figured it out as I went.)

```
import el.cam.contacts.configuration.ContactManagerConfiguration;
import org.apache.camel.spring.Main;

public class ContactManagerApplication {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactManagerApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setApplicationContext(createSpringApplicationContext());
//        main.addRoutesBuilder(contactManagerController); // DI using Spring Autowiring 
        main.run();
    }

    private static AbstractApplicationContext createSpringApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(ContactManagerConfiguration.class);
        appContext.refresh();
        return appContext;
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "el.cam.contacts")
public class ContactManagerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ContactManagerController contactManagerController;

    @Bean
    public CamelContext camelContext() throws Exception {
        SpringCamelContext camelContext = new SpringCamelContext();
        camelContext.addRoutes(contactManagerController);
        camelContext.setPropertiesComponent(properties());
        camelContext.addComponent("rest", rest());
        camelContext.addComponent("rest-api", restApi());
        camelContext.addComponent("jetty", jetty());
        return camelContext;
    }


    @Bean
    public PropertiesComponent properties() throws Exception {
        PropertiesComponent properties = new PropertiesComponent();
        properties.setLocation("classpath:application.properties");
        return properties;
    }


    @Bean
    public RestComponent rest() {
        RestComponent rest = new RestComponent();
        return rest;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestApiComponent restApi() {
        RestApiComponent restApi = new RestApiComponent();
        return restApi;
    }

    @Bean
    public JettyHttpComponent jetty() {
        JettyHttpComponent jettyHttpComponent = new JettyHttpComponent9();
        return jettyHttpComponent;
    }
```

Controller class:

```
@Component
public class ContactManagerController extends RouteBuilder {
    @Autowired
    ContactManagerService contactManagerService;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // before Camel-Spring, was using this to bind serviceBean in camel registry
//        getContext().getRegistry().bind("contactManagerService", new ContactManagerService());

        // TODO using default. camel property sources not picking up application.properties!
         restConfiguration("jetty").port("{{port:8282}}").contextPath("api")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
                .dataFormatProperty("disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS")
                .apiContextPath("api-doc")
                .enableCORS(true);

        // define the rest service
        rest("/contact-manager").consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
                .get().outType(ContactDto[].class)
                .to("bean:contactManagerService?method=getContacts(${header.contactType})")
        ;
    }
}
```